# Why Adyen return "Invalid shopper interaction"

Tags: adyen

I try to make a payment. 
I use drop-in like in this https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/drop-in-web guide. Then I send encripted card data (for example I add a "4000 0200 0000 0000" test card) as json string to the server (it uses "@adyen/api-library": "^2.1.6"). And then I try to make a payment:

```
  const config = new Config()
  config.apiKey = MY_API_KEY
  config.merchantAccount = MY_ACCOUNT
  const client = new Client({ config })
  client.setEnvironment('TEST')

  const checkout = new CheckoutAPI(client)
  try {
  const paymentsResponse = await checkout.payments({
    amount: {
      currency: 'USD',
      value: 10
    },
    paymentMethod: JSON.parse(paymentMethod),
    reference: "123456",
    merchantAccount: MY_ACCOUNT,
    returnUrl: 'http://localhost:3003/'
  })
  console.info(JSON.stringify(paymentsResponse))
```

And in console I see:

```
HttpClientException {
  statusCode: 422,
  name: 'HttpClientException',
  message:
   'HTTP Exception: 422. Unprocessable Entity: Invalid shopper interaction',
  errorCode: '000',
  .............................................................. (other)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer. "shopperInteraction" is not a required field. But if we don't send it, we get an error “Invalid shopper interaction”. See https://docs.adyen.com/api-reference/payments-api/paymentrequest. [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AATUz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the [adyen-node-api-library](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-node-api-library) and I've tested the same request on the latest version (v2.1.7) without sending the shopperInteraction and it worked. Which payment method type you are using? My request is using a payment through card. This field might be required for other payment methods type and optional for some.

Request:

```
 {
  "amount": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 10
  },
  "paymentMethod": {
    "type": "scheme",
    "cvc": "737",
    "expiryMonth": "10",
    "expiryYear": "2020",
    "holderName": "John Smith",
    "number": "4111111111111111"
  },
  "reference": "123456",
  "merchantAccount": MY_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT,
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost:3003/"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  ...
  "pspReference": PSP_REFERENCE,
  "resultCode": "Authorised",
  "merchantReference": "123456"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the field at the end

```
"returnUrl": "https: //your-company.com/...",
"shopperInteraction":"ContAuth"
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried with this

```
{
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": 10
    },
    "paymentMethod": {
        "type": "scheme",
        "number": "5555444433331111",
        "expiryMonth": "10",
        "expiryYear": "2020",
        "holderName": "John Smith",
        "cvc": "737"
    },
    "reference": "123456",
    "merchantAccount": "HugHubUK",
    "returnUrl": "www.google.com"
}
```

but getting error like

```
{
    "status": 422,
    "errorCode": "000",
    "message": "Please supply paymentDetails",
    "errorType": "validation",
    "pspReference": "881576842443252F"
}
```